# XAML Controls offsetting themselves, becoming invisible in Blend and browser

Tags: silverlight, xaml, layout, expression-blend, design-time

I'm having a problem, visible at runtime and in Expression Blend, where the text blocks (not text boxes, buttons, or custom controls) in my layout grid keep pushing themselves outside their cells, rendering them invisible. If I touch any of their properties in Blend (such as incrementing and then decrementing one of the margins), they become visible in Blend, but still not at runtime. Below is a screenshot showing the phenomenon in Blend. You see the design guides pointed to where the control should be, but its actual location above the top of the canvas.

[Controls are offset in Blend http://tinyurl.com/y9ttscf](http://tinyurl.com/y9ttscf)

**Update**:
Below I've posted the XAML, with the VisualStateGroups removed (since they add considerable complexity to the XAML and the problem manifests itself without them). The control selected above is "loginTextBlock" below.

```
<navigation:Page 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
    mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:UserControls="clr-namespace:MyClient.UserControls" xmlns:MyClient_Controls="clr-namespace:MyClient.Controls;assembly=MyClient.Controls" xmlns:controlsToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit" x:Class="MyClient.Views.Login" 
    d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480"
    Title="Login"
    >

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,16,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Name="loginTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Login" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,8"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="usernameTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Text="User name:" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="usernameTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,8,0,8" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="175" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" TabIndex="0" FontSize="16" Height="28" Padding="2"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="passwordTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Text="Password:" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            <PasswordBox x:Name="passwordBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,8,0,8" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="175" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" TabIndex="1" FontSize="16" Height="28" Padding="2"/>
            <Button x:Name="okButton" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,16,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96" Content="OK" Grid.Row="3" TabIndex="2" Click="okButton_Click" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <UserControls:StatusTextBlockControl x:Name="verifyingStatusTextBlockControl" Margin="8,16,8,8" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Verifying credentials..."/>
            <MyClient_Controls:LoginAttemptsCounter x:Name="loginAttemptsCounter" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="8" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="5" FirstFailureMessage="Please re-enter your Windows credentials.&#x0a;After 2 more failed attempts, your account will be locked." Height="30"/>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>

</navigation:Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, when my "LoginAttemptsCounter" control is in the grid (at the bottom), it was messing up the TextBlock controls. Instead, I changed my layout to wrap the grid within a StackPanel and place the LoginAttemptsCounter in the StackPanel below the grid rather than in the grid's bottom row. That has worked.

The key thing is that my custom control can't be within the same container (either the StackPanel or the Grid) as the TextBlocks.